# Amazon AWS S3 signed URL via Wget

Tags: amazon-s3, signed

I am able to create an Amazon S3 signed URL for a bucket in my account from which I can download and upload via the Amazon AWS CLI.

I have created the Amazon S3 URL as follows:

```
from boto.s3.connection import S3Connection
key = os.environ['aws_access_key_id']
secret = os.environ['aws_secret_access_key']
c = S3Connection(key,secret,is_secure=False)
bucket = c.get_bucket('my-bucket')
bktkey = bucket.get_key('stuff.tar.gz')
seconds=60*60*12
url2 = bktkey.generate_url(expires_in=seconds)
print '%s' %url2
```

Using `url2` and copy pasting it in Chrome, I get stuff.tar.gz downloaded.

But when I use Wget like so

```
wget <whatever is in url2>
```

I get the following exception,

```
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 403 Forbidden
2015-12-04 20:48:57 ERROR 403: Forbidden.
```

Why is Wget failing where Chrome and Firefox are successful in downloading using the signed Amazon S3 URL?

Comment: What is this code? Python? And why is it tagged with "signed"?

Answer (score 60):

I had the same issue. The fix is to use quotes:

```
wget -O test.tar.gz "https://bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/app1/10/10.2/test.tar.gz?Signature=hgbdhjJHGK&Expires=1454446963&AWSAccessKeyId=AAAAAAAAA"
```

Comment: The issue is that some of the characters in the URL have special meaning in the shell, which is why it fails in the shell but not in bash. For example, '&' tails bash to put a command in the background. So bash would only parse the URL that far before truncating it. Adding quotes around the URL causes bash to treat the URL as a string not bash command line arguments.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't expect the solution is as simple as adding quotes. I thought it is related to AWS protection or something similar.

Comment: This is the second time I've come to this exact answer to find the solution. Thanks!

Comment: Why is this not the accepted answer?