# Pre signing AWS S3 files

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, pre-signed-url

I have a bucket that allows for open files. I have uploaded a test file called `test.gsm` and have tried to presign the file by doing

```
root@server2:~# aws s3 presign  s3://dovid-ft/test.gsm  --expires-in 604800
https://dovid-ft.s3.amazonaws.com/test.gsm?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJSDPJKCCGAZ257VQ&Signature=0zbBU2B%2FKVrqgOXFQNTGh3gme%2Fo%3D&Expires=1625658191
root@server2:~#
```

If I then try to grab that file I get a 403.

```
root@server2:~# wget 'https://dovid-ft.s3.amazonaws.com/test.gsm?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJSDPJKCCGAZ257VQ&Signature=0zbBU2B%2FKVrqgOXFQNTGh3gme%2Fo%3D&Expires=1625658191'
--2021-06-30 07:49:21--  https://dovid-ft.s3.amazonaws.com/test.gsm?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJSDPJKCCGAZ257VQ&Signature=0zbBU2B%2FKVrqgOXFQNTGh3gme%2Fo%3D&Expires=1625658191
Resolving dovid-ft.s3.amazonaws.com (dovid-ft.s3.amazonaws.com)... 52.217.88.204
Connecting to dovid-ft.s3.amazonaws.com (dovid-ft.s3.amazonaws.com)|52.217.88.204|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 403 Forbidden
2021-06-30 07:49:21 ERROR 403: Forbidden.

root@server2:~#
```

I also tried to decode the HTML of the key to see if that would help and it did not.

```
root@server2:~# wget 'https://dovid-ft.s3.amazonaws.com/test.gsm?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJSDPJKCCGAZ257VQ&Signature=0zbBU2B/KVrqgOXFQNTGh3gme/o=&Expires=1625658191'
--2021-06-30 07:49:37--  https://dovid-ft.s3.amazonaws.com/test.gsm?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJSDPJKCCGAZ257VQ&Signature=0zbBU2B/KVrqgOXFQNTGh3gme/o=&Expires=1625658191
Resolving dovid-ft.s3.amazonaws.com (dovid-ft.s3.amazonaws.com)... 52.217.32.100
Connecting to dovid-ft.s3.amazonaws.com (dovid-ft.s3.amazonaws.com)|52.217.32.100|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 403 Forbidden
2021-06-30 07:49:37 ERROR 403: Forbidden.

root@server2:~#
```

Is there any way to get logs or see what the issue is and why my request is being rejected? As of now the only way to be able to get the file is to make it publicly available which I don't want to do.

Comment: Is the entity presigning the URL allowed to download it? If this is a real bucket name and you have made it public in some way I strongly recommend you change it in the question.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I was using the wrong credentials to presign the file. Why amazon didn't throw an error when I tried to presign them with the wrong credentials is beyond me.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is in wget. after recreating the scenario I wasn't able to download a file via wget also.
`wget -O test.gsm "https://yourURL"` # and will do.

reference: [Amazon AWS S3 signed URL via Wget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34101512/amazon-aws-s3-signed-url-via-wget)